# Activate root account without password in preseed file

Tags: system-installation, password, root, preseed

I need to create minimal preseed file that will activate root account without password.
I checked the forums but couldn't find anything useful.

**Disclaimer:**

I understand risks of root account without password, but this preseed file is required for
VM contextualisation which requires active root without password from fresh installation
and **will** set the password at the first boot.

Comment: " I checked the forums but couldn't find anything useful." You wont find anything. Your problem is with the VM. You need to set that up with SSH public key authentication. How you do is not Ubuntu related. Example with opennebula and kvm: https://docs.opennebula.org/5.2/operation/vm_setup/kvm.htmlhttps://docs.opennebula.org/5.2/operation/vm_setup/kvm.htmlhttps://docs.opennebula.org/5.2/operation/vm_setup/kvm.html

Comment: SSH public key is should be set in opennebula interface. After instantiation of VM opennebula inserts CD with those data into VM and one-context package will setup rest. But does requires root account withou password.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [our project](https://github.com/core-process/linux-unattended-installation). We embed an SSH public key into the preseed file and disable the root password. You can fork and adjust the scripts to your liking.

The project mentioned above provides all you need to create an unattended installation of a minimal setup of Linux, whereas minimal translates to the most lightweight setup - including an OpenSSH service and Python - which you can derive from the standard installer of a Linux distribution. The idea is, you will do all further deployment of your configurations and services with the help of Ansible or similar tools once you completed the minimal setup.